# Deleting old files in Windows 10 using forfiles

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to delete old files and folders in my Google Drive using a bat script on Windows 10 Home.

```
forfiles /M *.* /P "C:\Users\bruker\Google Drive\" /S /D -180 /C "cmd /c del /F /Q @path"
```

Gives the error message:

> ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '/F'. Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Simply remove the trailing backslash from the path. And remember this tool is named forfiles! Also you use the /M option. To see the output insert an echo in front of del.

Comment: Thank you LotPings! This solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The quotes aren't needed. Both `forfiles ... /C cmd /c del /F /Q @path` and `forfiles ... /C (cmd /c del /F /Q @path)` should work.

Comment: What if the file has a space in it?